# why does malloc(sizeof(pointer)) work?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, malloc

This following code works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    struct node{
        int a, b, c, d, e;
    };
    struct node *ptr = NULL;
    printf("Size of pointer ptr is %lu bytes\n",sizeof (ptr));
    printf("Size of struct node is %lu bytes\n",sizeof (struct node));
    ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof (ptr));               //Line 1
//    ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof (struct node));    //Line 2

    ptr->a = 1; ptr->b = 2; ptr->c = 3; ptr->d = 4; ptr->e = 5;
    printf("a: %d, b: %d, c: %d, d: %d, e: %d\n",
            ptr->a,ptr->b,ptr->c,ptr->d,ptr->e);
    return 0;
}
```

When complied as:

```
gcc -Wall file.c
```

My question is: why is this fine?

`malloc` allocates the number of bytes which are specified in it's argument. Here `sizeof ptr` is 8 bytes on my 64-bit linux machine. I thought `malloc` will provide 8 bytes but then how is it accessing all the variables a,b,c,d,e? Is it with gcc only or am I missing something with standard C?

As far as I know "Line 2" should be there instead of "Line 1" but either of the line works fine. Why?

Comment: The following may also work fine: `int* x = (int*)rand(); *x = 123;` that doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: C/C++ in combination with malloc does not check or verify that the size matches the size of the underlying type of the pointer to which the results are assigned - that's up to you.

Comment: Undefined behavior is *undefined*.  It might crash, it might appear to succeed, or it might erase your hard drive.  You can never be sure what will happen the moment you invoke undefined behavior, which includes reading/writing to memory beyond what you've allocated.

Comment: I am tempted to say: b/c it's not Java. With C, as long as you stay in the process memory you can write wherever you please (as long as the pages are not read-only)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have undefined behavior here.

`malloc` will allocate 8 bytes (as you say), but this cast is "bad":

```
ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof (ptr));
```

After this line, `ptr` will point to a memory block, which has only 8 allocated bytes, the rest are some "random" bytes. So, making

```
ptr->a = 1; ptr->b = 2; ptr->c = 3; ptr->d = 4; ptr->e = 5;
```

you actually change some memory, not only the allocated by `malloc`.

In other words, you are rewriting memory, you're not supposed to touch.

Answer (score 8):

Line 1 is incorrect and **won't** allocate sufficient space. If you can access the structure members later it is only because C does nothing to prevent you from accessing memory that doesn't belong to you.

Accessing `ptr->b`, `ptr-c`, etc., when you haven't allocated enough space for the entire structure is undefined behavior, and the next time that you run your code it could crash, or you could end up overwriting data in another part of your program.

To demonstrate the problem, allocate a second `struct node` immediately after the first. This isn't *guaranteed* to demonstrate the problem, but you're likely to see results similar to the following:

```
struct node *ptr = NULL;
struct node *ptr2 = NULL;

ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof (ptr));  // Your Line 1
ptr2 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));        // alloc another struct on the heap

ptr->a = 1; ptr->b = 2; ptr->c = 3; ptr->d = 4; ptr->e = 5;
ptr2->a = 11; ptr->b = 12; ptr->c = 13; ptr->d = 14; ptr->e = 15;

printf("ptr:  a: %d, b: %d, c: %d, d: %d, e: %d\n",
        ptr->a, ptr->b, ptr->c, ptr->d, ptr->e);
printf("ptr2: a: %d, b: %d, c: %d, d: %d, e: %d\n",
        ptr2->a, ptr2->b, ptr2->c, ptr2->d, ptr2->e);
```

Output:

```
ptr:  a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 11
ptr2: a: 11, b: 12, c: 13, d: 14, e: 15
```

Note that `ptr->e` has been modified by the assignment to `ptr2->a`, so you can see that one improperly-allocated structure is stepping on the memory of another. This certainly isn't what you want.

Comment: if line 1 is incorrect then after removing this line would give segmentation fault as there was no memory so we can't access structure members. May be I didn't get u.

Comment: not allocating memory for a structure, and allocating insufficient memory are both equally wrong, even though the second may cause a crash more often. Just because Line 1 **seems** to work doesn't mean that it's correct. Always use line 2.

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` is allocating only 8 bytes, but that doesn't stop you accessing memory beyond that. You will probably corrupt the heap and might write over other objects. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

In `ptr->a = 1; ptr->b = 2; ptr->c = 3; ptr->d = 4; ptr->e = 5;`you are accessing beyond the memory allocated by the malloc.
This is a case of [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and causes `undefined behaviour`.

It is possible because

```
 C and C++ provide no built-in protection against accessing or overwriting data
in any part of memory.
```

so, it may work sometime, sometime it may crash the program also.