# Passin a pointer to a pthread function result in losing his structure

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I'm trying to start a thread and giving to him a pointer to a structure. But the pointer received by the function isn't correct. I've got a piece of the structure correct but others aren't.

This is the function where the thread is started :

```
void start_pointer(struct fsm_pointer *pointer) {
    if ( pointer->started != 0 ){
        printf("CRITICAL : A pointer must be started only once");
        return;
    }
    pthread_create(&pointer->thread, NULL, &pointer_loop, (void *)pointer);
    pointer->started = 1;
}
```

And here the `pointer_loop` function :

```
void *pointer_loop(void * _pointer) {
    struct fsm_pointer * pointer = _pointer; // cast void pointer
    struct fsm_context init_context = {
        .event = event,
        .fnct_args = step.args,
    };
    // call pointer structure member => SEGFAULT
    pointer->current_step.fnct(&init_context); 
    return NULL;
}
```

The structures are defined as bellow :

```
struct fsm_pointer{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex_event;
    pthread_cond_t cond_event;
    struct fsm_event input_event;
    struct fsm_step current_step;
    unsigned short started;
};

struct fsm_step{
    void (*fnct)(const struct fsm_context *);
    void * args;
    struct fsm_trans transition;
};
```

**::EDIT::**
Here is where the `pointer` and `step` structures come to life :

```
struct fsm_pointer * create_pointer(struct fsm_step first_step)
{
    struct fsm_pointer *pointer = malloc(sizeof(pointer));
    pointer->thread = 0;
    pointer->mutex_event = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pointer->cond_event = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    pointer->input_event = _NONE_EVENT;
    pointer->current_step = first_step;
    pointer->started = 0;
    return pointer;
}

struct fsm_step create_step(void (*fnct)(const struct fsm_context *), void *args)
{
    struct fsm_step result = {
            .fnct = fnct,
            .args = args,
            .transition = TRANS_ENDPOINT,
    };
    return result;
}
```

And here is the function which manage it :

```
void test_new_fsm(){
    struct fsm_step step_0 = create_step(&callback, NULL);
    struct fsm_pointer *fsm = create_pointer(step_0);

    start_pointer(fsm);
    sleep(5);
    pthread_join(fsm->thread, NULL);
    sleep(1);
    free(fsm);
}
```

And the callback function is just for the test :

```
void callback(const struct fsm_context *context) {
    printf("Callback : event uid : %d \n", context->event.uid);
}
```

**::/EDIT::**

When I use a debugger (gdb) just before the segfault I can see that the pointer's address is correct (the same as before the thread creation) and that the `started` variable is correctly set to 1. But the `fnct` pointer is *NULL* which produce a segfault.

*When the exact same code (with correct variable names) as in the pointer_loop one is executed before the thread creation, there isn't any problem.*

So, does someone know what happens, or it's just an obvious mistake which is so obvious that more than a day of debugging isn't enough ?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you call `start_pointer`? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Where/how is `fcnt` set? You really need to create a MCVE as suggested. The problem may very well not be in the code you have shown (e.g. you may have a race condition where `fcnt` is being set to NULL before the thread executes.)

Comment: Sure, I had thought it could have been too much code and tried to show the minimal, but there was missing important parts. I've edited my post with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct fsm_pointer *pointer = malloc(sizeof(pointer));
```

should be:

```
struct fsm_pointer *pointer = malloc(sizeof(struct fsm_pointer));
```

or

```
struct fsm_pointer *pointer = malloc(sizeof(*pointer));
```

Comment: Solves the problem, I had only forgotten a `*` ... But what I do not understand is why the pointer is working if I use it before the thread creation ?

Comment: @Olivier see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745377/why-does-mallocsizeofpointer-work

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the code where the object of type `struct fsm_pointer` which `pointer` points to comes into existence, but presumably it is being modified, or its lifetime is ending, without synchronization with the newly created thread's access to it. Unless you have synchronization in the thread start function, and in the caller, to preclude concurrent access/end-of-lifetime, you will have to wait until you join the thread to free this structure or otherwise allow its lifetime to end.